# react - how to force an element to redraw immediately

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a toggle button in a react component:

```
toggleSpeak = () => {
   this.setState({buttonOn: !this.state.buttonOn});
}
```

And the button changes its style depending on its state:

```
 <img key="headphones" className={audioclass} src={this.state.buttonOn ? white : black} onClick={this.toggleSpeak}/>
```

This also triggers some stuff in a child component:

```
play={this.state.buttonOn}
```

This triggers some speechSynthesis playback, which sometimes takes a while.  The problem is that I want the user to realize that something is happening right away.  The button, however, doesn't change its style right away.  As long as I'm triggering something else, whether it is through a passthrough property to the child as above, or through triggering a redux action, it still delays changing color for a few seconds.

I want to change color right away without delay, so the user knows not to keep repushing it.  How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the "react" way of doing things, but I came up with a solution that works.  I split up the property I pass to turn on the player from the button toggle.

```
state = {
   buttonOn: false,
   play: false
}
```

Button attributes are the same as above, changing with the buttonOn state.

ChildComponent property:
  ... play={this.state.play}

Then, on the button toggle event I wait a half a sec before I change the play state.  This is so the button will update it's style right away, and then all the player stuff can run after a tick.

```
  togglePlay = (newValue) => {
    this.setState({play: newValue}); 
  }


  toggleSpeak = (e) => {
    let newValue = !this.state.buttonOn;
    this.setState({buttonOn: newValue});
    if (this.state.play != newValue) {
      setTimeout(function() { 
         this.togglePlay(newValue);
      }.bind(this), 500);
    }
```

Then of course clear the timeout function on dismount:

```
  componentWillUnmount() {
   clearTimeout(this.togglePlay);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you doing the speechSynthesis in render?
You should call the function that does the speechSynthesis after toggling the button.
As far as UX is concerned, I would recommend that you show a loading indicator while you are doing a task that might take some time to finish. Also, you could disable the button until the speechSynthesis is finished.

```
toggleSpeak = () => {
  if(!this.state.doingSpeechSynthesis) {
    this.setState(
      {buttonOn: !this.state.buttonOn, doingSpeechSynthesis: true}, 
      () => speechSynthesis(args, this.setState{doingSpeechSynthesis: false}));
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`this.setState({})` function is indeed asynchronous so what you are claiming is likely to be true for a very short number of milliseconds considering that all you have in the trigger is

```
toggleSpeak = () => {
   this.setState({buttonOn: !this.state.buttonOn});
}
```

The noticeable delay you speak of should be unnoticeable. I would think that the delay is being imposed from elsewhere. (say you require some other synchronous code to run before `this.setState({})`. Do show us more of the relevant code so that we can get better grasp of what's happening.